# jQuery invoke function if anywhere on the site is clicked except one area

Tags: jquery, function, event-handling

I have a dialog that I reuse a lot. However now my client wants it so when ever someone clicks somewhere not on the dialog assuming its open. They want it to close, however when you click anything within the dialog it remains open for its functional needs.

Right now I am using $(body).click(function(){}) for my notion of closing it if its open which works when its open. However if I click on something in the dialog it closes the dialog to, so I am looking for a workaround but I am completely lost in where to begin on such a work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the not selector

```
$("*").not("#dialog").click(function(event){
    $("#dialog").hide();
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: ha, never thought of trying it that way, you sir are genius!